Will sideways 2x4 on shower walls pass inspection
I am building two L shaped bathrooms next to each other. I am limited on space. I wonder if building two of the shower wall with 2x4 oriented sideways (90° turn) will is in compliance with IRC

For non load bearing walls it should.  The 2x4s are not much more than something to nail/screw wall panels(drywall/shower board) on.

@crip,  print that as an answer.

@RMDman   Would like to, but do not know code to be sure.   OP needs a code monkey to answer correctly.

@crip659: in this context, I would say code lawyer, by analogy with "language lawyer" when talking about computer specs.

What will the showers be finished with? If they are acrylic, no problem. If they are tile, there is where I would see an issue

@Jack, (probably get in trouble for chatting here)  I'm intrigued now.  I can't think of a code that would disallow this, but I'm not saying there isn't.   If it's not load bearing, would the risk not be with the builder?  Like if tiled it may be too flimsy and tile will crack?

@RMDman yes that is the way it would go and the reason why I asked what is the finish of the shower. An acrylic shower stall will stay ridgid against that wall where a tile wall with the slightest movement will crack. There are other versions of shower walls that could handle it too, like Wetwall by Wilsonart and others like that.

You could call your local inspector and ask? :)
